# Which explicit type did I get back from Enumerable.Select

Tags: c#, linq

I've have the following code example from Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx):

```
String[] fruits = {"apple", "banana", "mango", "orange", "passionfruit", "grape" };
var query = fruits.Select((fruit, index) 
  => new {Substring = fruit.Substring(0, index)});

foreach (var obj in query)
  Console.WriteLine("{0}", obj);
```

This works quite well, but what I m not understand is  what type of query is?

I ve tried to get out the info from the debugger but i was not able to declare it and write it down explicitly. I ve tried several variants e.g.

```
IEnumerable<int,string> query = fruits.Select((fruit, index) 
  => new {Substring = fruit.Substring(0, index)});
```

but this does build at all. How can I define the query type explicit without using var?

Comment: Why do you not want to use `var`? It is still strongly typed.

Comment: [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) ... _"the type name is generated by the compiler and is not available at the source code level. The type of each property is inferred by the compiler."_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot specify type because it is `anonymous`. Read more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Answer (score 2):

When you use the new operator without a specific type, then the compiler creates an anonymous type that you can't refer to explicitly. If you want to be able to refer to it, then you should either create your own class to return explicitly, or return a pre-existing class. Try:

```
IEnumerable<string> query = fruits.Select((fruit, index) => fruit.Substring(0, index));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, if you really *must* specify the type (and there really is no need to - an anonymous type is just as type-safe) then you must first declare a class/struct

```
public class FruitySubstringyThingy
{
    public string Substring{get;set;}
}
```

and use that in the projection

```
IEnumerable<FruitySubstringyThingy> items
  = fruits.Select((fruit,index) => new FruitySubstringyThingy{Substring = fruit.Substring(0, index)});
```